# Android Chat Application Architecture with websocket

Tags: architecture, database, rest, websockets, android-development

I'm trying to build chat application in Android (future maybe webapp also) using websockets. The purpose of this project is to familiar with websockets, get know websockets and real time applications. Right now I'm able to send/broadcast the messages to all clients(android) connected to the websocket server running on my local machine. I am using okhttp to create websocket connection to the nodejs websocket server. The websocket server is implemented using nodejs and ws. All the users and and messages right now gets deleted after all the sockets closed.

So basically what I wanted to do is to be able to authenticate the user before connecting to the websocket server. I will need a database and not sure which one yet. I was thinking of creating a REST API to authenticate the clients and use token for validating the user. I am not sure if the websocket server and REST API should be separate running? Also, what is your advice for authenticating the user through REST API and web socket server? Also, once the client's data is stored in db, is it okay for websocket server to query the database for validating/verifying the connected user and storing chat messages? Please advice for the architecture as I am beginner and wanted to learn how this component interacts with each other. If there are other approaches also it will be very helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure if the websocket server and REST API should be separate running?

Server-Sent Events (SSE) or WebSocket both share the same characteristic: the HTTPS connection remains open for a long time.

In an ordinary API, if you have 500 clients, it means that you may have maybe 5 concurrent connections, maybe 50, depending on how fast the responses are and how frequently the clients are accessing the API. With SSE and WebSocket, you will have at least 500 connections, and likely a few more because of the reconnects.

This means that if SSE/WebSocket shares the same infrastructure with the API, you can sometimes create your own denial of service. If your server has a limit of 1.000 connections, this means that as soon as you reach a number of clients close to a thousand, your API will become randomly unaccessible.

Therefore:

- If the current use is way below the capacity of the infrastructure, you can put WebSocket and the API together.
- If the current use can potentially reach the infrastructure limits, you have to dissociate WebSocket from the API.

> Also, what is your advice for authenticating the user through REST API and web socket server?

Whatever works for you. If you're using HTTPS client certificates, for instance, the authentication is transparent, and there is no extra code needed. If you use cookie-based sessions, the WebSocket request will contain them as well. If you authenticate the client at every request to the API, do the same for WebSocket.

> Also, once the client's data is stored in db, is it okay for websocket server to query the database for validating/verifying the connected user and storing chat messages?

What makes you think it is okay for the API to do it, but not for the WebSocket? What makes WebSocket so special?

Comment: Hi Arseni, first of all thank you for the response. So basically, the API and WebSocket can be together or not. I didn't know about that. For authentication and adding users, I was thinking of creating a REST API and genererate token to pass to the websocket connection. Do you think it is a good idea? Also, regarding the question about if it is okay for API and not for WebSocket, I was just thinking that it slow down the websocket server? but as you said both have the same characteristics and I think it is normal for websocket server to have access to the database and do queries.

Comment: @AustinVillanueva: (1) as your API can be hosted on one, two, ten or one thousand servers, WebSocket can be on its own server, and either interact with the API, or share the database, or communicate through an MQS. (2) Just to be sure, you're using an existing authentication mechanism such as OpenID, not reinventing your own, right? (3) Regarding slowing down WebSocket, if you're talking about blocking operations, you can do the queries asynchronously.

Comment: Hi Arseni, I see.. I understand now. I will try to look for OpenID. I'm not familiar with it. Thanks for all the recommendation and feedbacks.

Comment: @AustinVillanueva: I haven't said you *have* to use OpenID. There are lots of alternatives. What I said, however, is that you should use one of the existing solutions, and never write your own, because you *will* get it wrong and introduce security issues.

Comment: Hi Arseni, yeah, that's what I understand. It is not particularly OpenID that I should use but the similar solution. OpenID is only one of the alternatives and I don't need to create my own. Thanks again.